# Number to text decoding

Tags: text, decode

Can anybody help me come up with an algorithm or way to decode a number to 3 characters when they are encoded in the following manner:

Each element represents 3 alphabetic characters as in the following examples:

DOG -> (3 * 26^2) + (14 * 26) + 6 = 2398

CAT -> (2 * 26^2) + (0 * 26) + 19 = 1371

ZZZ -> (25 * 26^2) + (25 * 26) + 25 = 17575

So say I have 7446 or 3290 how would I go about converting them to text?

Answer (score 3):

Try this to extract the letters in reverse order:

```
7446             % 26 = 10
(7446 / 26)      % 26 = 0
(7446 / 26 / 26) % 26 = 11
```

For example:

```
1371             % 26 = 19 (T)
(1371 / 26)      % 26 = 0  (A)
(1371 / 26 / 26) % 26 = 2  (C)

CAT
```

The `%` refers to the [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). `x % y` gives you the remainder of the division `x / y`.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo

```
input = 2398
iteration = 1
while input > 0
    character = input % 26
    input = input - character
    input = input / 26
    print character
```

Comment: just noticed that if you add a colon after the while statement this becomes valid python 2.x code